# How to fill a column using 2-d array as a lookup (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in a spreadsheet that has some values. I have created an array allocating these values to a group. I want to fill the 2nd column using a lookup from the array until the last row.

Current view:

```
column A
A
B
C
A 
...
```

Target view:

```
column A    column B
A            1
B            2
C            3
A            1
...
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim Array as Variant
Dim lr as long
numlookup=(Array("A", 1), Array("B",2), Array("C",3))

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:A" & lr).Formula = "=IF(application.match(ActiveCell.Value, numlookup,0)".cell(numlookup,1).value
```

Thank you!

Comment: Note you cannot use `Array` as a variable name this is a reserved key word.

Comment: If your logic is `A=1; B=2; C=3` then you can assign a value in column B using a simple `if` statement (e.g. `IF(A1 = "A", 1, IF(A1 = "B", 2, 3))`)

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I want to create a rule, rather than embed the fixed If statements, in case lookup grows longer or changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to separate code and data (hard coding data is a very bad practice). Therefore it is a bad idea to hard code the grouping in an array `Arr=(Array("A", 1), Array("B",2), Array("C",3))`. Instead you would want to keep this data in a (maybe hidden) worksheet.

So your `GroupLookup` sheet would look like that

```
column A    column B
A            1
B            2
C            3
```

Then you can use a simple [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) in your data sheet

```
column A   column B
A          =VLOOKUP(A:A,GroupLookup!A:B,2,FALSE)
B
C
A 
...
```

---

Edit due to comment:

If you need to do it with VBA still put your `GroupLookup` in a worksheet not into a code! Eg into your add-in or where ever you put your macro also but the following sheet:

So your `GroupLookup` sheet would look like that

```
column A    column B
A            1
B            2
C            3
```

And lookup the groups in that sheet with the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup)

```
Option Explicit 

Sub WriteGroups()
    Dim GroupLookup As Worksheet 'define workbook/sheet where the group lookup table is
    Set GroupLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GroupLookup")


    With Workbooks("YourWb").ActiveSheet 'this is the sheet where the group is written to
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = 1 To LastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            .Cells(iRow, "B").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(.Cells(iRow, "A").Value, GroupLookup.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then .Cells(iRow, "B").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) 'write #NA if group not found
            On Error Goto 0
        Next iRow
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Completely agree on `VLOOKUP`. Original approach seriously tried to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you, need a a fixed array (lookup will not change), as this array needs to be applied using macro to multiple spreadsheets which do not have this lookup. Basically I have raw data which is received as multiple excel spreadsheets, and by running the macro, it need to process the data by running the VBA code without creating a lookup within each of the spreadsheets.

Comment: @jillm_5 see my edited answer. If you need to perform this on another sheets data, you will still put your GroupLookup into a worksheet (eg. within your addin) or where ever you put the macro. Never hard code data into VBA code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you! Accepted the answer.